# Set maximum number input text from database in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I have an input text that is used to determine the amount of the purchase of item in my shopping cart. Each item has a different maximum amount of purchases, the maximum number of purchases (max) is obtained from the mysql database. I want if user input the number of items exceeds the maximum limit, then a warning appear.

The shopping chart and the amount :

[image]

The database example:

```
id_item | item          | brands    | max
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1       | Baskom Sedang | Lion Star |2
2       | Pinset Anatomi| Selako    |5
3       | Tromol        | Selako    |7
```

So for example if i type 3 in the "Baskom sedang" amounts (exceeding max limits), i want alert to appear.

I know I'm supposed to include a javascript/code that I try, but I do not have any idea about the javascript, i'm not good with javascript. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to solve it:

- Transfer max info to front-end
- Check when user submit
- Asynchronous data check, like `Jquery` ajax

**Transfer max info to front-end**

Just placed your max info into some hidden area, and use javascript to get and check that.

```js
function check(obj){
  var max = obj.getAttribute("data-max");
  if(parseInt(obj.value) > parseInt(max)){
    alert("Amount out of max!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="amount" value="0" data-max="3" onkeyup="check(this);"/>
```

But this way is **not recommended** and should be avoided, since users can achieve your storeage data by checking source code.

**Check when user submit**

Check the amount with max value at server-side, which leads to poor user experience.

**Asynchronous data check**

This is mostly recommended and used, which get data asynchronously. You can try `jquery`.

Assuming your server-side lang is `php`, you can make a file `checkMax.php`:

```
<?
  $amount = $_POST["amount"];
  $item_id = $_POST["item_id "];
  /* get your max data from database using item_id, then assign $max
     ...
  */
  echo $amount > $max ? 1 : 0
```

Then you can check amount by jquery ajax.

```
<input name="amount" class="amount" data-id="1" value="0"/>
$(".amount").change(function(){
  var amount = $(this).val();
  var item_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $.post("checkMax.php", {"amount": amount, "item_id": item_id}, function(data){
     if(data == "1")alert("Amount out of Max!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try first.. :)

Comment: hmm, there's no error, it's just nothing happened when i type the amount > max... -_-

Comment: First, dircetly visit `checkMax.php` with parameters set, to see if the result echoed is right. Second, alert(data) in the `$.post` callback and check.

Comment: oh my bad my bad, i forgot to include the connections :), it's works now, but the alert is appear more than once, so i need to keep click the ok alert more than once until it's disappear, and after i click the alert closed, the alert will appear again if i didn't delete/change the amount..

Comment: Yes it triggers every time the value changed, and the `alert` function is just for testing, you can change it to any other logics you want.

Comment: hmm, but i change the amount to > max and then click ok from the alert, the alert disappear, but then appear again even though I didn't do anything... -_-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69266/discussion-between-bandon-and-muhammad-fahmy).

Comment: I already have the solution for that, you really helped me, thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you are looking for? [Limit numerical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384074/limit-input-box-to-0-100)

Just would need to grab the value from the database and change the upper limit appropriately.

Comment: @Muhammad Fahmy just tested it and it works. Let me know how you go.

Comment: More or less like that, One thing I haven't been able to is, how to grab the value from database to javascript?

Answer (score 1):

it's easy to validate with server side.

the logic is like this.

if user click checkout or submit , then get max from database , then compare it with user input , if input more than max then show error.. :D

Comment: yeah, i could do it with submit method, but my boss want to validate it when user typing the input text.. -_-