# Prevent minimum and maximum values entered

Tags: javascript, async-await, switch-statement

I am am trying to prevent a user from going from a specific number value parameter from say 1 to 9999.99. I have multiple input values that I have assigned ids. I am using a switch statement to set the parameters (min & max) of these, so first would be from 1 to 9999.99, the second be 1 to 999.99, the third 1 to 99.99. However, I can still enter over these values and don't get dinged on my restrictions could some one please provide insight, still trying to work this through. Thanks for any help

```js
function getMinMax(ctrlId) {
  let min = 0;
  let max = 9999;
  switch (ctrlId) {
    case "aID":
      min = 1;
      max = 99999.99;
      break;
    case "bID":
      min = 1;
      max = 999.99;
      break;
    case "cID":
      min = 1;
      max = 99.99;
      break;
       }
  return { min: min, max: max };
}

async function checkMinMax(ctrl) {
  let value = await ctrl.value();
  if(value === '') return;
  let ctrlId = await ctrl.id;
  let minMax = getMinMaxForField(ctrlId);
  let isNotANumber = Number.isNaN(value);
  if(!isNotANumber && Number.parseFloat(value) >= minMax.min && Number.parseFloat(value) <= minMax.max) {
    ctrl.value(value);
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a value between  ' + minMax.min + ' and ' + minMax.max + '.')
    ctrl.value('');
  } 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set maximum number input from database in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619582/how-do-i-set-maximum-number-input-from-database-in-javascript)

Comment: the use of async await seems unnecessary ... an elements `id` is not a Promise,, and perhaps you're getting errors (look in your browsers developer tools console) when trying to use the elements value as if it were a function ... it isn't, and you also don't need to await that ... there is nothing asynchronous happening in checkMinmax, so don't use async/await - and finally you assign the value using assignment, since value is not a function